# always get weird errors in android build. EXPO

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, eas

I am generally new to react native app dev using Expo.

whenever i am creating an app in expo. It works fine when i run it using

```
npx expo start -c
```

when i build the android build or push an update using

```
eas update --branch preview
```

Then when i run the updated original app on android mobile. It always crashes without any reason due to a error which it never showed when i was running it using "npx expo start -x"

I then have to open the app in emulator and check the logs using

```
adb logcat *:E
```

Which is too much work. Like the error logging in that is too overwhelming. And finding the error which makes my app crash is a hassle.

SO

MY QUESTION is that am i doing something wrong in the development process which is making the process so exhausting and tedious. Is there a method by which i can run the android build locally to find out errors before pushing an update.